# Looking for a children's scifi/mystery/horror book about a boy who becomes addicted to an arcade game

Tags: story-identification, books

It's about a kid/teen who gets addicted to a VR-like arcade game. Every time he went to the arcade, there was nobody around the game, even though it was really cool/high-tech. I can't remember much about it, but it really reminds me of the game Superhot and the Polybius urban legend. It was probably published in the 1990s or early 2000s, and iirc the title was only one word - the name of the arcade game. I think the cover art was blueish or purpleish. The book was definitely for children/teens, and was written like a Goosebumps book, from what I can remember.

Answer (score 2):

You might be thinking of *[Mindmaster](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/3088900-mindmaster) (1997)* by Clive Gifford.

[image: Front cover of Mindmaster]

[LibraryThing](https://www.librarything.com/work/1788527) offers a brief synopsis:

> Pete Clark, grieving the death of his father, becomes caught up in the world of arcade games at The Zone, a gaming hall run by a mysterious and dangerous man who just may have found the link between the computer and the human brain.

The back of the book, which can be read at [this preview from archive.org](https://archive.org/details/mindmaster0000giff/page/n1/mode/2up), has another synopsis:

> Just imagine... an arcade game that can read your mind and play with your darkest thoughts. Just imagine... a machine that steals your dreams. Just imagine... the Mindmaster. There is no escape.